# Hook to run afer config import

Tags: 8, configuration

I need to run some code after the config for my module is imported(it will create/update a css file that depends on configuration). So what is the correct hook to use? The module install will run only on first time when the module is instaled.

Comment: Can't this be done via [`hook_page_attachments_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments_alter/8.2.x)? Load the config in there and attach/detach a library accordingly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The config system has switched already to events and the documentation for events describes in "My First Drupal 8 Event Subscriber" how to subscribe to a config event:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/subscribe-to-and-dispatch-events

See also this example from the Color module:

*/core/modules/color/src/EventSubscriber/ColorConfigCacheInvalidator.php*

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\color\EventSubscriber;

use Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheTagsInvalidatorInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigCrudEvent;
use Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

/**
 * A subscriber invalidating cache tags when color config objects are saved.
 */
class ColorConfigCacheInvalidator implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  /**
   * The cache tags invalidator.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheTagsInvalidatorInterface
   */
  protected $cacheTagsInvalidator;

  /**
   * Constructs a ColorConfigCacheInvalidator object.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheTagsInvalidatorInterface $cache_tags_invalidator
   *   The cache tags invalidator.
   */
  public function __construct(CacheTagsInvalidatorInterface $cache_tags_invalidator) {
    $this->cacheTagsInvalidator = $cache_tags_invalidator;
  }

  /**
   * Invalidate cache tags when a color theme config object changes.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigCrudEvent $event
   *   The Event to process.
   */
  public function onChange(ConfigCrudEvent $event) {
    // Changing a theme's color settings causes the theme's asset library
    // containing the color CSS file to be altered to use a different file.
    if (strpos($event->getConfig()->getName(), 'color.theme.') === 0) {
      $this->cacheTagsInvalidator->invalidateTags(['library_info']);
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[ConfigEvents::SAVE][] = ['onChange'];
    $events[ConfigEvents::DELETE][] = ['onChange'];

    return $events;
  }

}
```

Comment: I can use the ConfigEvents::IMPORT for what i want. I was searching for the hook, but the right way now is with events.